# Provisioning Profiles and Archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

For my application, in it's build settings I'm required to specify the provisioning profile and code signing certifcate:

[image]

Then when I perform a Product->Archive and go on to Distribute the app using the "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment" I'm asked yet again what provisioning profile I want to use:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: It's an annoying requirement, I have struggled with this question as well.

Comment: The build settings provisioning profile setting came about in xCode 5.  My guess is because the build process had too few possible screw-ups available, they added one more.  (in other words, I have no idea)

Comment: Has anyone tried if the build can be resigned with a different profile than the one that was compiled with ?

Comment: @SuleaCosmin I haven't tried for a while, but this has never worked for me before.

Comment: Worth a try ... they've changed that part in latest xcode (I will also try it first time I get to that window)

Comment: @SuleaCosmin I've done this for xcarchives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117375/preparing-an-unsigned-xcarchive/21588437

Answer (score 0):

You can create an archive which would be managed by Xcode and would be present unless you delete it. Based on need you can export , sign with different profile if needed. You can send to multiple testers using different profiles/ distribute to required audience.

On the resigning part, The IPA can be resigned. Look into this tool iResign ( https://code.google.com/p/iresign/downloads/list ).