# How to build and sign an iOS app on separate machines?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcodebuild

We have an iOS app which is built using a series of Bash scripts run by Jenkins. As things are today, we build an xcarchive using this command:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace "..." -scheme "..." -configuration "Release" -archivePath "..."
```

This builds the app and signs it using the certs specified in the provisioning profile which is set using an xcconfig. Once it is complete, we then turn it into an IPA using:

```
xcodebuild -archivePath "..." -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist "${export_options_plist}" -exportPath "..."
```

This IPA can then be uploaded to Hockey or to the App store depending on the xcconfig we use (we swap them out to create different builds).

We now want to make sure our certificates are kept safe as much as possible. This means we want to perform the build on one machine, but the signing on another. In order to do that, we need to do this:

1. Create an unsigned xcarchive
2. Transfer the xcarchive to the signing machine
3. Turn the xcarchive into a signed IPA

Step 2 can be ignored for now though, so lets just focus on steps #1 and #3.

Creating the unsigned xcarchive can be done by adding the arguments `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO` to the `archive` command.

Signing the IPA is much trickier though. We assumed we could just create the IPA again and use the `codesign` command to sign the binary in the IPA. This had a couple of problems though. The first is that the `.entitlements` file we had for the app wasn't respected. We had to pass this as a flag to the signing command. Then we realised that we had to correct all the variables in the `.entitlements` file since Xcode was no longer replacing them with the correct values. Then we realised that we had to do this for each extension we had.

We finally got this all working, with the correct entitlements, replacing the variables and everything was signed, but when I tried uploading the new signed IPA to Hockey it rejected it. The error message wasn't helpful either.

We diff'ed a build with the previous system with the new system and each binary was different. We're not sure if this is a codesigning issue, or just a timestamp change, but there are changes. Furthermore, we discovered that my extensions are all missing `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` files, plus possibly more issues.

It definitely seems like we are going about this the wrong way. We clearly shouldn't have to re-do everything just to sign on a different machine, so where are we going wrong? How are we supposed to build on one machine and sign on another?

P.S. Our current tools use `xcodebuild` directly, but we have support for `fastlane` for other parts of our build process, so we are happy to use it if needed.

Update: We have a "solution" to this which is to sign the Release builds with a dev cert, then resign them using the distribution one. This solves all the problems with entitlements being populated etc. but still requires each binary to be resigned and entitlements combined, etc. so I'm curious if there is a better solution.

Comment: Hi Dale Myers, In xcode seven I was using following commands for building ipa files from command line xcodebuild  clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO  -scheme helloworld clean archive -archivePath build/helloworld

xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "build/helloworld.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/myipa.ipa" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO      but now with xcode 9 I am stuck and struggling for some solution from last two weeks. If you have any solution please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We worked on this for several weeks along with other teams in the company. All of us came to the same conclusion, there is no better option than signing with a dev cert and then re-signing each and every binary with the prod cert afterwards. It's not a straight forward process, but that's what we have been left with.

Comment: Hi Dale Myers, Can you please share some sample code for creating archive and then exporting ipa Based upon your research for xcode 9 e.g. xcodebuild -workspace helloworld.xcworkspace -scheme helloworld -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/helloworld.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the steps to create an unsigned xcarchive

1. Set ‘Code Signing Identity’ = ‘Don’t Code Sign’

•   Select Targets (‘’) -> Build Settings and find the ‘Signing’ section.

•   **Set ‘Code Signing Identity’ = ‘Don’t Code Sign’**

[image]

2. Set Bundle Identifier = ‘’

Set Version = 1.0 //That you need to send

Set Build = 5  //That you need to send

**Remove ‘Automatically manage singing’ flag.**

[image]

3. Open the terminal and go to the project root folder. Then run the following command.

`xcodebuild -workspace <ProjectName>.xcworkspace -scheme <ProjectName> -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/<ProjectName>.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO`

4. After successfully completing, it will create a new ‘buildArchive’ folder and inside that a ‘.xcarchive’ file.

You can Zip that ‘.xcarchive’ file and transfer the xcarchive to the signing machine.

Comment: This worked like a dream, however it no longer works in XCode 10, as they removed the "Don't Code Sign" option.

Comment: To get this script to work on Xcode 10.2.1, you have to add `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO`, so the script above becomes:

`xcodebuild -workspace <ProjectName>.xcworkspace -scheme <ProjectName> -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath buildArchive/<ProjectName>.xcarchive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you I think

1. Create an unsigned IPA on your build machine.
2. Have a script in the build machine that transfers the IPA to your
   signing machine.
3. Use the [FloatSign](https://gist.github.com/mediabounds/1367348) script on the signing machine to resign the
   IPA.

Comment: Creating an unsigned IPA causes problems with lack of entitlements and FloatSign doesn't handle things like resetting the debugging key in the entitlements.