# Xcode 10: Where is the don't code sign option in Code Signing Identity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, archive, unsigned

I'm building a Unity iOS app for a client in the form of an unsigned XCArchive as the client signs the XCArchive manually for security reasons.

I was following this guide beforehand: [How to build and sign an iOS app on separate machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372139/how-to-build-and-sign-an-ios-app-on-separate-machines/48213556#48213556)

But I recently updated Xcode to 10.0, and now the option for `don't code sign` under `Target->Build Settings->Code Signing Identity` is missing, which is a bit of an issue when it comes to building the XCArchive.

How can I build an XCArchive without the `don't code sign` option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Simply select: `Other`

  - [image]
- Remove what is wrote there (leave the little window empty), then close

  - [image]
- Then ->  `Code Signing Identity` = empty == `Don't Code Sign`

  - [image]

Comment: @ChrisComeau  Where do you from there (10.1)? I have archived the app. Distribute to Development (team) seems to ask me to select certificate and iOS Development profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it was removed. Apple force us to do code signing anyway. But it is not a problem (if you have developer account). You can sign your `.ipa` with your own identity and then your client will resign it. To avoid problems with resigning choose proper method of distribution when exporting `.ipa` in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

- Previous：updated `Synny`'s answer.
- Now: verified `Code Signing Identity = empty` != `Don't Code Sign`, and:

## `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO` == `Don't Code Sign`

`PROJECT`/`TARGETS` -> `Build Settings` -> click `➕` -> `Add User-Defined Setting` -> add new para:

- `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO`

  - [image]